# View all files (in a list) associated with a given Trello board

Tags: trello

I would like to be able to see a list of all the files that have been uploaded to the cards comprising a given board in Trello.

Is that possible?

Comment: **What** web application are you talking about?...

Comment: @iglvzx She is talking about Trello (it's tagged with "trello").

Comment: @babak That is apparent now, but when I commented, this was not specified. Also, Annelie was not the one to add that. It is a reasonable assumption, however.

Answer (score 1):

Getting a list of all uploaded files is *not* possible at this time. However, we are tracking this as a feature request.